# phonegap build ios app not showing custom icon and splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am using windows 10. When i am developing an android and ios app using phone gap. I am building apk and ipa from http://build.phonegap.com . The android app work as fine and showing custom icon and splash screen but in ios it is not showing custom icon and splash screen. In ios application the icon and splash screen are showing default cordova image. How to solve this problem. My source code is shown below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.faz.lp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>LP</name>
<description>LP</description>
<author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com"></author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />



<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />

<splash src="splash.png" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="25000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
<icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png"/>
    <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png"/>
    <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png"/>
    <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png"/>
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png"/>
    <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"/>
    <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png"/>
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png"/>
    <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png"/>
    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png"/>
    <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
    <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"/>
</platform>
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
    <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
    <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
</platform>
<platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
    <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
</platform>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open xcode and and images in specified assets. and replace default cordova images

Comment: I have no mac device

Comment: Is there any way to do in windows 10

Comment: Add a virtual machine using VM Ware and add xcode manually(not app store)